# Jest test not firing parent onClick function in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

So I'm testing out the following child component that receives a function from the parent in its prop:

```
export interface IProps{
  parentClick: () => void;
}

export class Child extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
    handleClick = () => {
      this.props.parentClick();
  }

  render () {
    return ( <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button> )
  }
}
```

In my Jest test I'm doing the following to check that `this.props.parentClick` is fired:

```
  it("button click fires", () => {
    const props = {
      parentClick: jest.fn();
    }

    const Child = enzyme.mount(<Child {...props} />);
    Child.find('button').simulate('click'); //shouldn't this trigger parentClick?
    expect(props.parentClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But the test fails saying:

`Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.`

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get an error on `mount(<Child {...props} />);`, since `Child` should be undefined or a reference error due to the constant having the same name as the already defined class. Try using a lower case name for the constant: `const child`.

Comment: It was a typo. It is in lower case in my code.